# LAME.framework for Apple Silicon / M1

Tags: frameworks, lame, apple-silicon

I found this for IOS, but I need help getting LAME.framework to build for MacOS intel AND arm64.

https://github.com/Superbil/build-lame-for-iOS/blob/master/build_ios.sh

Can anyone point me to a build script similar to this please? Target is Big Sur if that makes a difference.

Frameworks are a mystery to me so I have been lucky finding these in the past.
No idea how to create this.

PS I did try to change the iphonesdk line(s) to macOS, but it fails (no sdk in path)
Probably not the right way to do it anyway.

Comment: Just trying to see if anyone has this. I need this for my native app. I am willing to host an M1 if someone needs a machine to compile.

Comment: Did you manage to build LAME for M1 arm64? I'm in the same position.

Comment: Bump. Still looking for lame framework for Apple silicon / intel fat. Someone has this working….

Comment: I did this for a product a couple of years ago. Looking at the notes I built LAME indepently for Intel and AppleSilicon and then created the fat binary with the lipo command.    lipo -create -output universal/libmp3lame.a intel/libmp3lame.a arm/libmp3lame.a